# plotly: how to show broken axis

Tags: python, plotly, axis-labels

I need to depict a "broken axis" in my plot because some of the values are huge. For an example consider:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import numpy as np
y=np.arange(20)
y[0]=1000
go.Figure(go.Bar(
    y=y
))
```

[This question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Prmis.png) discusses the same for matplotlib, but I need to use plotly.

Here is an example of what I would like to create.
[image]

Comment: As far as I know, you cannot do that with Plotly. You can with matplotlib.

Comment: Yeah thx allot for the clarification

Comment: @NICO You're welcome =) Instead of posting the same question twice, please consider providing a code snippet along with a data sample, what kind of figure you're able to produce as well as some description of your desired result. As it now stands, your linked plot is hardly readable. Doing so will increase your chances of receiving a useful answer considerably. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) s a good  place to start

Comment: Questions that ask "where do I start?" are typically too broad and are not a good fit for this site. People have their own method for approaching the problem and because of this there cannot be a _correct_ answer. Give a good read over [Where to Start](//softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6367) and [edit] your post.

Comment: Question is valid, fixed the way it is asked.

Answer (score 4):

One way to overcome this problem, is to have two sub-frames as follows:

```py
import numpy as np
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots

y = np.arange(20)
y[0] = 1000

color = px.colors.sequential.Plasma[0]
cut_interval = [30, 700]
bar = go.Bar(
    y=y,
    name="foo",
    marker_color=color,
)
fig = make_subplots(
    rows=2,
    cols=1,
    vertical_spacing=0.05,
    shared_xaxes=True,
)

fig.append_trace(bar, row=1, col=1)
bar.showlegend = False
fig.append_trace(bar, row=2, col=1)

fig.update_yaxes(range=[cut_interval[1], max(y) * 1.1], row=1, col=1)
fig.update_xaxes(visible=False, row=1, col=1)
fig.update_yaxes(range=[0, cut_interval[0]], row=2, col=1)
```

This will result to:

[image]

The two sub-frames are joined on the x-axis, so it is possible to pan them.